# Retrieve items text inside dropdown list xpath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I have a select like this

```
<select name="super_attribute[93]" data-selector="super_attribute[93]" data-validate="{required:true}" id="attribute93" class="super-attribute-select" aria-required="true">
<option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
<option value="131">Green</option>
<option value="20364">Black</option>
<option value="20365">White</option></select>
```

I want to get the items text from the drop-down list (Green, Black, White) using CSS selector or Xpath

I tried the following

```
response.xpath("//*[(@id = 'attribute93')]").extract()
```

for some reason it only returned the first value

```
[u'<select name="super_attribute[93]" data-selector="super_attribute[93]" data-validate="{required:true}" id="attribute93" class="super-attribute-select"><option value="">Choose an Option...</option></select>']
```

Comment: You are not selecting `option` elements, but the `select` element. You only show _one_ `select` element in your input document. Are you sure that what you are showing is the full output? Please show more of your Python code so that people can run it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Xpath :

```
//select[@id="attribute93"]/option[position()>1]/text()
```

Comment: response.xpath('//select[@id="attribute93"]/option[position()>1]/text()').extract()

 , it is returning an empty array

Answer (score 0):

To select all of the `<options>`, your CSS query will be:

```
select#attribute93 option
```

Comment: this did not worked for me, response.xpath('select[name="super_attribute[93]"] option').extract() | ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in select[name="super_attribute[93]"] option

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realise the `<select>` element had an `id` - I've updated the CSS selector to something more straightforward. Try: `select#attribute93 option`.

Comment: this returned no error but only got the first option 
>>> response.css('select#attribute93 option').extract()
[u'<option value="">Choose an Option...</option>']

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting `option` elements, of which there are several, but the `select` element. You only show *one* `select` element in your input document.

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> body = """<select name="super_attribute[93]" data-selector="super_attribute[93]" data-validate="{required:true}" id="attribute93" class="super-attribute-select" aria-required="true">
... <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
... <option value="131">Green</option>
... <option value="20364">Black</option>
... <option value="20365">White</option></select>"""
>>> response = Selector(text=body)
>>> response.xpath("//*[(@id = 'attribute93')]").extract()
['<select name="super_attribute[93]" data-selector="super_attribute[93]" data-validate="{required:true}" id="attribute93" class="super-attribute-select" aria-required="true">\n<option value="">Choose an Option...</option>\n<option value="131">Green</option>\n<option value="20364">Black</option>\n<option value="20365">White</option></select>']
```

The output is a list with one single element, but it is not what you posted in your question (at least with scrapy `1.8.0`): all the child `option` elements are included.

Using the correct XPath expression from [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59825749/1987598):

```
>>> response.xpath('//select[@id="attribute93"]/option[position()>1]/text()').extract()
['Green', 'Black', 'White']
```